# How to create an efficient and fast scoring system in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of a python project, I need to develop a fast and efficient notation system to rate objects. To briefly explain, I have several rating criteria that I call A, B, C, C, D... Each criterion is evaluated with a score out of 10.

I have to evaluate a dictionary that has as its key the criteria of the notation (A, B, C, D...) and as values, the value to be noted.

The problems are:

1. The data to be evaluated can be of several types: int/float/date.
2. A score of 10 can be assigned to the highest value (number of items
   sold for example) or in some cases the lowest (number of order
   cancellations)
3. Each scoring criterion must be weighted
4. The algo must be optimized and fast to note objects in real time

So I started on a JSON to group my scoring criteria with an evaluator method.

My json file :

```
{
  "A": {
    "weighting": 2,
    "graduation": {
      "10": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 0],
      "9": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 1],
      "8": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 2],
      "7": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 3],
      "6": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 4],
      "5": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 5],
      "4": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 6],
      "3": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 7],
      "2": ["lesser_than_or_equal", 9],
      "1": ["great_than", 10]
    }
  },
  "B": {
    "weighting": 3,
    "graduation": {
      "10": ["greater_than_or_equal", 10000000],
      "9": ["greater_than_or_equal", 1000000],
      "8": ["greater_than_or_equal", 100000],
      "7": ["greater_than_or_equal", 10000],
      "6": ["greater_than_or_equal", 1000],
      "5": ["greater_than_or_equal", 100],
      "4": ["greater_than_or_equal", 50],
      "3": ["greater_than_or_equal", 30],
      "2": ["greater_than_or_equal", 20],
      "1": ["less_than", 20]
    }
  },
```

And here is my code:

```py
class Notation(object):
    def assign_notation(self, score, criterion='A'):
        try:
            grade = self.get_grade_for_criterion(self.fetchScoringSystem('scoringSystem.json'), criterion)
        except Exception as exc:
            logger.error('Impossible to retrieve the criteria scale '+criterion+' : ' + exc)
        else:
            grades = grade['graduation']
            for key in sorted(grades, key=int, reverse=True):
                evaluator, param = grades[key]
                if self.__getattribute__(evaluator)(score, param):
                    return (int(key) * int(grade['weighting']))
                else:
                    raise AttributeError
                    logger.error('Unable to access the function '+evaluator+' with the parameters '+ score + param)

    def fetchGradingScale(self, infile):
        import json
        from collections import OrderedDict

        with open(infile, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        logger.info("Read file %s", infile)
        return data

    def greater_than_or_equal(self, score, x):
        try:
            return score >= x
        except ValueError as exc:
            logger.error('Error in values :' + exc)

    def lesser_than_or_equal(self, score, x):
        try:
            return score <= x
        except ValueError as exc:
            logger.error('Error in values :' + exc)
```

For the moment, python returns the following error: 
 TypeError:'int' object is not iterable

However, I think my assign_notation method is not efficient and a friend told me about bissect to optimize the algorithm. Have you already built a complex notation system and if not, do you have any ideas to help me build it?

Comment: It is preferable to include the full error trace, so we're not trying to guess which line caused the error or what was the context leading up to it.

Comment: The error if located in the assign_notation function to the line : 
evaluator, param = grades[key]

Answer (score 0):

You're describing more of a "cost function" than an "algorithm", here. Sometimes people will call it a "figure of merit" or FoM, when several KPIs are jammed into a single unitless number.

> 2. A score of 10 can be assigned to the highest value (number of items sold for example) or in some cases the lowest (number of order cancellations)

That makes little sense, you need "goodness" to uniformly correspond to, say, high values, and then "badness" to low values.
Simplest fix is to flip it with `(10 - score)` for criteria which are "backwards".
Once having made that score adjustment, you'll be free to drop your current tracking of greater / lesser.

I assume dates won't stay that way, but will be converted to a number, like `days_old`, that is handled much like the other criteria.

Define weights for all criteria, and compute the weighted sum.
Piece of cake.
Choosing weights from the unit interval, 0 .. 1, will probably be most convenient.
The weights do not *need* to sum to 1.0, but that would certainly help when humans are interpreting the inputs, and their contribution to the output.

> TypeError:'int' object is not iterable

```
                evaluator, param = grades[key]
```

It looks like you were hoping to unpack a 2-tuple, but `grades[key]` turned out to be just a single integer, like `7`.
The `get_grade_for_criterion()` function will need to be careful about returning correctly formatted results.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Why do you think the weight should be in the range[0.1]? I don't quite understand the interest at the moment.

The idea of doing (10 - score) is excellent but in this case, how to differentiate the normal criteria from the "backwards" criteria? 

I just took a look at the FoMs but I couldn't find any useful information. Do you have an article to advise me on FoM?

The idea after having the notes is to go through a decision tree to determine the best objects